# Play framework with JPA initial insertion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I use Play 2.3 with Hibernate.
On starting up the application the first time, I want to have some data inserted into the database as default values.

In my case I have an entity class "Studycourse". All tables are created through JPA on first run.

I use DB evolution (1.sql) to insert the default data, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO studycourse (id, title) VALUES (1, 'Computer Science');
```

This works when using the normal "activator run" command. But if I do "activator test" and start a simple integration test with inMemoryDatabase(), I get following error:

```
[error] play - Table "STUDYCOURSE" not found; SQL statement: INSERT INTO studycourse (id, title) VALUES (1, 'Computer Science')
```

I guess, that the initial JPA setup is not done in the in-memory DB.

Question: Is there a best practice on how to do this?

The integration test looks like:

```
public class IntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
            public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
                browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
                assertThat(browser.pageSource()).contains("Your new application is ready.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We use http://flywaydb.org, which I find more powerful than Play's native evolutions, and we assume that tests are run *after* the database migrations have taken place. So in local dev, I don't run tests until I've done the db migrations, and in our build environment, Jenkins does the database migration and then does tests.

Comment: Thank you Josh Padnick for your remarks. I'll take a look onto flywaydb as my team is searching for a solid tool for DB migration anyway. In the meantime, I see, if it is possible to "clone" the current DB into the testing in-mem or just work with the dev DB instead of the in-mem DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question was essentially asking "How can I execute my JPA initialization steps in a test environment so that my in-memory database is populated when I run integration tests involving my database?".

My answer will not directly address that but it will summarize how we solve the same underlying issues you're trying to solve.

My interpretation of your objectives is that you want to:

- Establish a good practice for database schema migration
- Establish a common practice for database integration testing

**Database Schema Migration**

As I mentioned in my comment above, we use http://flywaydb.org for database schema migrations and it has been an outstanding tool.  Flyway has an SBT plugin so you can run `flywayClean` and `flywayMigrate` right from `activator` to delete and re-initialize your database instantly.

Flyway supports sophisticated file name versions so that you can execute SQL scripts like `v1.1.0.sql`, `v1.1.1.sql`, and `v1.2.0.sql`.  Flyway will also complain if you try to execute migration scripts that are not a pure improvement on the existing state of the database.  This means we're using flyway to push database schema migrations to production, resting confident that this will fail if we've done something silly.  Of course, we always take a DB backup right before the migration just to be safe.

Finally, Flyway will even let you execute java programs to populate the database in case you want to use service methods instead of just raw SQL.

Anyway, your choices here are basically Play evolutions, Flyway, or Liquibase.

**In-Memory Database vs. Dev-Database**

On this issue, I've seen two primary positions:

1. Never test on an in-memory database because then your tests won't
   reveal the subtle differences between your in-memory database and
   your production database, or
2. Use an in-memory database for local testing, but at least have your
   build server use a dev database.

You can see, for example, the comments at the end of http://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/26/stop-unit-testing-database-code/.

Option #1 gives you higher speed overall, but delays the feedback time between writing bad code and getting a failing integration test.

Option #2 gives you slightly lower speed overall, but gives you immediate feedback on the real database.

As with most things in engineering, there is no "best" solution, just a set of tradeoffs which make the most sense for your team.

**Choosing an ORM Layer**

We initially began with Hibernate but eventually switched to http://jooq.org.  See http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/jooq-a-really-nice-alternative-to-hibernate for a jOOQ-positive overview, and http://blog.jooq.org/2012/04/21/jooq-and-hibernate-a-discussion/ for a good discussion on the two.

Hibernate seemed attractive to us because it was so mature and so popular, but when we began running into classic SQL vs. Object-Oriented impedance mismatches like how to handle inheritance, Hibernate required a learning curve and some setup overhead.

We reasoned that, if we're going to incur that overhead at all, why not just use SQL directly to do the mappings?  So, we switched to JOOQ and have been able to write some very clean, elegant, and testable code.  If you're not too far down the hibernate path, I would encourage you to take a look at jOOQ.

If you're already deep into Hibernate, and it's working well for you, there's probably little value to switching.

**Best Practices for Database Integration Testing**

I wondered this exact question and posted about it at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/GkBW5ZGdgwQ.  Lukas, the author of jOOQ responded with some general remarks.

At this point, we integration test most of our DAO's and service classes.  Our tests are run after `flywayClean` and `flywayMigrate` have been run.  Then, each test is written to clean up after itself.  The biggest issue is performance, which so far is not a problem, but may be an issue later.

I also posted on that and received a helpful answer. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/BgOCIgz_9q0/jBy8zxejPEkJ.

*Disclaimer: we are close to launching our app but not yet running it in production, so others may have additional best practices to add.*